# How to force delete Docker image with terraform destroy

Tags: docker, nginx, terraform, hcl, terraform-provider-docker

I was following [a tutorial on terraform.io](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/install-cli?in=terraform/aws-get-started) that has me provision a docker image and container using terraform, and then destroy the terraform stack. However, I get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to remove Docker image: 
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 540a289bab6c (must be forced) - 
image is being used by stopped container ae12197d265d
```

I know the native Docker solution to this is just running `docker rmi -f 540a289bab6c`. However, I was wondering if there's a terraform approach to this?

The docs for the terraform resource `docker_image` show the reason terraform attempted to destroy the image upon `terraform destroy`: the template `main.tf` had `keep-locally` set to `true`. But it doesn't say how to force that destruction.

The `main.tf` from the tutorial is as follows:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    docker = {
      source = "terraform-providers/docker"
    }
  }
}

provider "docker" {}

resource "docker_image" "nginx" {
  name         = "nginx:latest"
  keep_locally = false
}

resource "docker_container" "nginx" {
  image = docker_image.nginx.latest
  name  = "tutorial"
  ports {
    internal = 80
    external = 8000
  }
}
```

So how do I force `terraform destroy` to work on this template without resorting to manual intervention using docker native tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message indicates that there is another container relying on the same image. It could be that a separate docker container provisioned outside of terraform and using the same nginx docker image in the tutorial. Check your `docker ps -a` to see if there is such container if so just run `docker rm -f <container_name>`to remove it and your terraform destroy should work.

Comment: Yes! I had stopped containers from 10 months ago that relied on the ngnix image too. After removing those, the `terraform destroy` worked.